# SQL join with complex case condition

Tags: sql, join

I need to build a query to get the following details.

**Table 1**

```
Code  Text
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

**Table 2**

```
Code  Min  Max
1  1.00  1.75
2  1.76  2.25
3  2.26  3.00
```

**Table 3**

```
Eid  Value
1234  1.2
3456  2.56
```

I am looking at a query which gives me the following output in a single SQL query.
Table 3, should look at the Value, compare the value in Table 2 to see if it lies between Min and max and get the equivalent code and get the code compare with the Table 1 and get the final Text value.

**Final Output**

```
Eid  Text
1234  A
3456  C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way to do this

```
select t3.eid,t1.text
  from t3
  join t2
    on t3.value between t2.min and t2.max
  join t1
    on t2.code=t1.code
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select eid,text
from table3 t3 inner join table2 t2 on t3.Value>=t2.min and t3.Value<=t2.max
inner join table1 t1 on t1.code=t2.code
```